# Creating local Jenkins user account possible if using LDAP?

Tags: jenkins

In our Jenkins instance we use the LDAP plugin to be able to log in with our credentials from the AD domain.

Now, we want remotely (from our GIT machine) call a build job on Jenkins. For logging in credentials are necessary. For this purpose, we need a service account on Jenkins. Can we create the account on Jenkins locally? Or do we need one on AD?

In the scenario described above: can we use user's API token? We'd prefer this method instead of name/pwd.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the job configuration, under the Build Triggers section, there is a checkbox for "Trigger builds remotely". Setup an Authentication Token and then you can run the job using the specified token instead of having to pass over credentials. Then, according to the handy explanation already there under the Authentication Token box, you can:

> Use the following URL to trigger build remotely: JENKINS_URL/job/NameOfYourJob/build?token=TOKEN_NAME or /buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN_NAME
>   Optionally append &cause=Cause+Text to provide text that will be included in the recorded build cause.

This is how I handle most of my remote job executions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To this purpose you need to create a system user in AD to execute the build outside. This user needs to have permissions to run builds and the user and password in AD can´t expire and won't change